# International arrival and departure at SFO

Tags: transit, sfo

If I arrive at SFO from New Zealand and then have a connecting flight to Calgary, will I still have to collect my luggage, go through immigration, then re-check in my luggage, go through security?

Is 2.5 hours enough time for this?  Do I need a USA visa even though I'm just in USA for 2.5 hours?

Comment: What is your country of citizenship?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Airports in the USA don't have sterile transit areas, so you need to technically enter the country and depart an hour later. Depending on what country you're from, you'll need a visa if you don't qualify for ESTA/VWP.

Comment: Nothing "technical" about it: it's the same full-sized immigration rumba as for entering the US for any other reason.